# How would I remove the CTKLabel from a label using customtkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, label, customtkinter

I have this code:

```
import customtkinter
import random

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")

# Create a list to track the names that have already been chosen
chosen_names = []

def button_callback():
    # Create a list of names
    names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dave", "Eve"]

    # Randomly select a name from the list
    name = random.choice(names)

    # Check if the name has already been chosen
    while name in chosen_names:
        name = random.choice(names)

    # Add the name to the list of chosen names
    chosen_names.append(name)

    # Get the label
    label = app.winfo_children()[0]
    # Update the label text
    label.configure(text=name)
    label.grid_remove()

    # Check if all the values in the list have been selected
    if len(chosen_names) == len(names):
        app.destroy()

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.title("Randomizer")
#replace with image
app.iconbitmap('isologo.ico')
app.geometry("500x500")

# Create a label
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app)
label.pack(padx=0, pady=0)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Selector Nombre", command=button_callback)
button.pack(ipadx=20, ipady=20,padx=20, pady=50)

app.mainloop()
```

When I run the app on top, I get a "CTkLabel" where the random names would go How would I make that label never appear?

Also, is there a way so that when my list finishes, it restarts? I added the destroy function because I don't know if this is possible. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: image reference]

Comment: Set `text=""` to override the default value `"CTkLabel"`.  Also `label = app.winfo_children()[0]` is not necessary because `label` is already a global variable that can be accessed directly.

Comment: if change the text=""  nothing is displayed the other part thanks hadn't caught ir

Comment: Only need to set `text=""` when creating the label.

Comment: I see what you mean yeah that works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the default value of the `text` option of `CTkLabel` is `"CTkLabel"`, so it will be shown if `text` option is not given.  Just to set `text=""` to override the default value if you don't want to show anything.

To restart the random selection if all the names have been selected, you need to clear `chosen_names` before getting a random choice from `names`:

```py
...

def button_callback():
    # Create a list of names
    names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dave", "Eve"]

    # Check if all the values in the list have been selected
    if len(chosen_names) == len(names):
        # clear chosen_names to restart
        chosen_names.clear()

    # Randomly select a name from the list
    name = random.choice(names)
    # Check if the name has already been chosen
    # or the same as the current one
    while name in (chosen_names or [label.cget("text")]):
        name = random.choice(names)
    # Add the name to the list of chosen names
    chosen_names.append(name)

    # Update the label text
    label.configure(text=name)
    label.grid_remove()

...

# set text="" to override the default value "CTkLabel"
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="")
...
```